# UISpy in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does Visual Studio .NET 2008 come with UISpy?  I ask this for for the reason that my copy of VS installed, but everything else pretty much errored out and I want to know if I need to fix it for UISpy (not worried about compact framework or device emulators).  Thanks.

Edit:

As noted below, I saw it is part of the SDK, but was wondering if any of the SDK was included in the vs2k8 install.  Thanks All.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available in [version 7 of the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en).  VS2008 came with version 6.0a.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx), it is part of the Windows SDK. It appears, though, that it is not part of the 2008 version of the SDK.  Microsoft might have dropped the ball on this one -if you need it it sounds like you'll need one of the older SDKs.